# Am new to Android field.I want to get HTTP get reuest from php,,using asyntask

Tags: php, android, http, android-asynctask

Am simply confused with the process .I want to pass the TextView and Edittext1 & Edittect2 value to Second.java ,,And By using httpget want to get data from login.php,And give the output the mainclass during onclick event....Help me ,,,Thanks in advance.

```
package com.example.messagebox;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class MessageBox extends Activity {
    private static final String USER_AGENT = null;
    private static String username,password,role;
    //private String link="http://192.168.1.12:81/arun/loginpost.php";
    private static String result, user , pass;
    private static HttpResponse response;
     private static BufferedReader in;
     private static StringBuffer sb;
     private EditText message,date;
     private TextView message_view,tview;
     private Button btn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.message_box);
        message = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.message);
        date = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.date);
        message_view = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_msg);
        tview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.output_text);

        btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.message_box, menu);
        return true;
    }
    private void login() {

    }
}
```

Its is my second.java class for Asynctask

```
package com.example.messagebox;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class Second extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
    public Second(Context context,TextView statusField) 
    {

    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
         try{

                String username = "arun";
                String password = "arun";
                String link = "http://192.168.1.12:81/arun/login.php?username="
                +username+"&password="+password;
                URL url = new URL(link);
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
                request.setURI(new URI(link));
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader
               (new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

               StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
               String line="";
               while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                  sb.append(line);
                  break;
                }
                in.close();
                return sb.toString();

          }catch(Exception e){
             return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
          }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }



}
```

This is my xml

```
   <EditText
      android:id="@+id/editText2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText1"
      android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
      android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
      android:ems="10"
      android:inputType="textPassword" >
   </EditText>

   <EditText
      android:id="@+id/editText1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
      android:ems="10" >

   <requestFocus android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

   </EditText>

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:text="@string/Username" />

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView3"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:text="@string/App"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView7"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView5"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView6"
      android:text="@string/Role"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
      android:textSize="10sp" />

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView5"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
      android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
      android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editText1"
      android:text="@string/LoginRole" />
   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView8"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_above="@+id/textView6"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
      android:layout_marginBottom="27dp"
      android:text="@string/method" />

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView4"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView8"
      android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
      android:layout_marginTop="86dp"
      android:text="@string/LoginStatus" />


   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView6"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView4"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:text="@string/Status"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
      android:textSize="10sp" />

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView9"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView8"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView6"
      android:text="@string/Choose"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
      android:textSize="10sp" />

   <Button
      android:id="@+id/button2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView6"
      android:onClick="loginPost"
      android:text="@string/LoginPost" />

   <Button
      android:id="@+id/button1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button2"
      android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
      android:onClick="login"
      android:text="@string/LoginGet" />

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText2"
      android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText2"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:text="@string/Password" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: don't use AsyncTask as a separate class. use this class in MainActivity

Comment: I have tried that also ,But it shows android.os.networkexception error

Comment: because you didnt add the INTERNET permission in AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: post your AndroidManifest.xml code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this code will help you.

```
public class MessageBox extends Activity {
private static final String USER_AGENT = null;
private static String username,password,role;
//private String link="http://192.168.1.12:81/arun/loginpost.php";
private static String result, user , pass;
private static HttpResponse response;
 private static BufferedReader in;
 private static StringBuffer sb;
 private EditText message,date;
 private TextView message_view,tview;
 private Button btn;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.message_box);
    message = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.message);
    date = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.date);
    message_view = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_msg);
    tview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.output_text);

    btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListner((OnClickListener) this);

}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.message_box, menu);
    return true;
}

private void onClick(View v) {
new sendPostData().execute();
}

 private class sendPostData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
        @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

String line="";

 try{

            String username = "arun";
            String password = "arun";
            String link = "http://192.168.1.12:81/arun/login.php?username="
            +username+"&password="+password;
            URL url = new URL(link);
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
            request.setURI(new URI(link));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader
           (new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

           StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");

           while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
              sb.append(line);
              break;
            }
            in.close();
            return sb.toString();

      }catch(Exception e){
         return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
      }

    }
       @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //View your result here.
            message_view.setText(line);
        }
 }

   }
```

And don't forget to add the permission in Manifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: It shows error in  btn.setOnClickListener(this);
The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (MessageBox)

Comment: add cast argument to this listner. like btn.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);

Comment: By using btn.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
My activity unfortunately stops

Comment: i have edited the Answer now try this. have you heard about debugger?

Comment: use debugger and check there is the issue. which point causing your application stopped.

Comment: U mean DDMS,,,otherwise i dont know,,,

Comment: do u have Teamviewer, Will let you know what is debugger and how to use it ?

Comment: no not exactly the DDMS .. click Windows on top and then click on Open Perspective and then click on debug.

Comment: how to get json data in input fields.

Comment: your services response you in JSON?

Comment: I mean that php-json enconded data,,,,Is it the same process..?

Comment: yeah almost the same process .. but for that you have to create a web service thru which you start communication between an android and server. then your service will send you a JSON string which you parse in android application.

Comment: yeah you neeed a server side programming as well as a class for parsing a JSON.

Comment: How can i insert data in mysql database using httppost